# How to prevent Visitors from being able to share documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am exploring the SharePoint communications site. Can Visitors share documents? If yes, then is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitors with read permission also can share.

You could limit sharing through site sharing settings.

Go to Settings -> Site Permissions -> Change how members can share and Access requests.

[image]